# Why doesn't Bruce take a running jump when trying to escape from the pit?

Tags: character, the-dark-knight-rises

When Bruce gets the hardest part of escaping the pit, the big jump, he stands at the edge and jumps from there.

There is clearly room on the ledge he is standing on for him to take a running jump. Obviously a running jump would enable him to jump a lot further.

Why would Bruce not take a running jump?

Comment: my initial hunch is the case of the old state of the prison,we see it broke in the prior attempt when bruce uses a rope. so he might have decided to take a leap forward from where he was standing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I seem to remember the whole point of the exchange (before Bruce made his final attempt) between him and the doctor was that he had to be scared to be able to make it out - Bruce had told his cell mate several times that he wasn't scared.

Maybe the fact that he had to be scared meant that he had to walk to the edge and jump from there. The fear of not making it from a standing jump could have given him what he needed to make it. At least, that's my interpretation.

Comment: I don't remember Bruce doing a running start in his first attempt _(before the doctor's advice)_ either. Maybe there simply wasn't enough space, or the curvature of the wall was a hindrance.

Comment: @Jamie Taylor I think you may have made a mistake. It wasn't that Bruce Wayne had to be scared, it is the opposite. Bruce wasn't scared of dying, but scared of dying in the pit while his city burns.